# Distributing API calls to users for web app

Tags: api, web-applications

We are trying to call one of Google's APIs and analyze the data and then display it for the user on our site. We realize we can make calls to the API through our server using php or python, but because of Google's limit, we are looking for an option that will have the API call come from the user, instead of our server. Is there a way for a web app to distribute the requests amongst the users instead of make all the calls from our server?

Thank you very much as this has been a tricky one to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that this is possible. The API request is per API key and you can't provide every user with their own API key.

If the scenario you are trying to achieve requests possibly the same data for multiple users. I highly suggest you save/cache the API request. This will minimize the times your server send API request to google since you saved that request to your server. You can then set an expiration for your saved/cached API request to renew X days.

Scenario

user 1: request data for item 123 from API.
server: sends request to API server, and save

user 2: request data for item 123
server: return saved API response